# send() function on socket does not return -1 for never/unconnected socket

Tags: c, sockets

I am experiencing a strange behaviour for send() function the call , where socketfd is 0, p is "test\n" , length is 5 , flags is 0 :

```
  size_t n = 0;

  n = send(socketfd, p, length, flags);
```

send seems to return a value in n 18446744073709551615

The function documentation says it returns -1 on error.

The code is compiled on mac os x 10.7 lion. any ideas what's going on ?

Comment: What's the tipe of the variable n? And how do you test its value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size_t` is an unsigned type, it can't contain negative values.
In fact if you check the manpage of send, its return type is `ssize_t`, which is the signed version and can contain negative values.

Try changing the type.

Comment: Even if the return type is not signed, if I look at the hexadecimal version of the number, it is 0x1999 9999 9999 9999 which is not -1 either. Even if the data type was unsigned, the hex format should have been 0xFFFFFFFF.

Comment: @Ganesh you missed the last `5`.

Comment: @Gerhardh.. Thanks for pointing out. I just left it generic, but you are correct.